# HTML: show different sized tables on the same page depending on the user's choice

Tags: html, django, frontend

Is it possible to implement two different sized tables where only one would be displayed on the page depending on the user's choice?

E.g.: user chooses data table which has the following columns: country, price, date, so 3 columns would be displayed.
Then the user chooses the users table with columns: name, email, so now 2 columns would be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input")
const country = document.querySelectorAll('td.country')
inputs.forEach(e => e.onchange = ({
  target: {
    checked,
    name
  }
}) => {
  document.querySelectorAll(`td.${name}`).forEach(e => e.style.display = checked ? "table-cell" : "none")
})
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>table</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td class="country">country</td>
        <td class="price">price</td>
        <td class="date">date</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="country">USA</td>
        <td class="price">234</td>
        <td class="date">3-9-2022</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="country">fr</td>
        <td class="price">234</td>
        <td class="date">3-9-2022</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="country">dz</td>
        <td class="price">234</td>
        <td class="date">3-9-2022</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>


  <div>
    <h5>what to display : </h5>
    <div><label>show country : <input checked type="checkbox" name="country" id="country"></label></div>
    <div><label>show price : <input checked type="checkbox" name="price" id="price"></label></div>
    <div><label>show date : <input checked type="checkbox" name="date" id="date"></label></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

i think this will do the job ?

Comment: Would this work for 2 different tables? I am not looking to hide a specific column, but rather display a different table (from the one currently shown), with different column names and different column size. So If i select User table, a table with attributes name and email would be displayed. If I select the data table, then another table should be shown, with attributes country, price, date